# building with gradle and deploying to web and app servers

Tags: javascript, java, gradle, war

I am new to gradle and am developing a web app for calendar and scheduling. I want to deploy the html, css, and javascript to an Apache web server and the war to Tomcat through gradle.

I have successfully built a war for my servlet. I am manually deploying the war using Tomcat's manager for now. I am directly coding in the Apache server's webroot on my local machine.

The build.gradle file is pretty generic -

```
plugins {
    id 'war'
}

repositories {
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:28.0-jre'
    providedCompile 'javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:3.1.0' 
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

What is a proper location for non-java code in gradle project?
How do I integrate plugins for checking/linting javascript code?